# Guid.Parse() or new Guid() - What's the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

What is the difference between these two ways of converting a string to `System.Guid`? Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

```
var myguid = Guid.Parse("9546482E-887A-4CAB-A403-AD9C326FFDA5");
```

or

```
var myguid = new Guid("9546482E-887A-4CAB-A403-AD9C326FFDA5");
```

Comment: in terms of what ?

Comment: You can also use :  Guid.TryParse()

Answer (score 107, accepted):

A quick look in the Reflector reveals that both are pretty much equivalent.

```
public Guid(string g)
{
    if (g == null)
    {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("g");
    }
    this = Empty;
    GuidResult result = new GuidResult();
    result.Init(GuidParseThrowStyle.All);
    if (!TryParseGuid(g, GuidStyles.Any, ref result))
    {
        throw result.GetGuidParseException();
    }
    this = result.parsedGuid;
}

public static Guid Parse(string input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }
    GuidResult result = new GuidResult();
    result.Init(GuidParseThrowStyle.AllButOverflow);
    if (!TryParseGuid(input, GuidStyles.Any, ref result))
    {
        throw result.GetGuidParseException();
    }
    return result.parsedGuid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was really looking for "is their a difference in how they work".

Comment: Looks like there's a clear difference in the GuidParseThrowStyle used, so one could throw an error for input that the other will not.

Comment: @Triynko: If you look at the code, you will see that they both throw for the same causes. The only difference is that if an `OverflowException` is thrown it will be encapsulated in a `FormatException` in case of `Guid.Parse`.

Answer (score 33):

Use the version that is the most readable to you.  The two are implemented almost exactly the same way.

The only real difference is that the constructor initializes itself to `Guid.Empty` before attempting the parse.  However, the effective code is identical.

That being said, if the `Guid` is coming from user input, then `Guid.TryParse` would be better than either option.  If this `Guid` is hard coded, and always valid, either of the above are perfectly reasonable options.

Answer (score 13):

I tried performance on one milion guids and Guid.Parse seems to be a insignificantly faster. It made 10-20 milisecods difference of 800 miliseconds of total creation on my PC.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int iterations = 1000 * 1000;
        const string input = "63559BC0-1FEF-4158-968E-AE4B94974F8E";

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            new Guid(input);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("new Guid(): {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            Guid.Parse(input);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Guid.Parse(): {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

And output:

**new Guid(): 804 ms**

**Guid.Parse(): 791 ms**

Comment: This isn't a statistically significant benchmark. I ran this multiple times and got varying results. The background noise clouds any possible performance differences in these implementations.

Answer (score -3):

In .Net framework v1.1 exists only 1 way -> var myguid = new Guid("9546482E-887A-4CAB-A403-AD9C326FFDA5");

Guid.Parse became available later.

Comment: Please provide an explanation along with solution so the user has a better understanding of what the code is doing.