Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FK
I'm creating a POST API to insert data into my Walks table and it has two ForeignKey with Difficulties and Regions table and this is my Walk model
public class Walk
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double LengthInKm { get; set; }
    public string? WalkImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    public Guid DifficultyId { get; set; }
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }
   

    public Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
}

I don't know why conflict happen because I checked the all the table and model. I seeded data in Regions and Difficulty and it's still not working.
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        
    }
    public DbSet<Difficulty> Difficulties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Walk> Walks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var difficuties = new List<Difficulty>()
        {
            new Difficulty()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("ce6a68d1-b490-4d38-a162-21ce3c371bfa"),
                Name = "Easy"
            },
            new Difficulty()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("f5a9b531-a099-493a-a05a-81c95627adbc"),
                Name = "Medium"
            },
            new Difficulty()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("261f60b6-efa7-426d-8ea4-7b34cf9beba1"),
                Name = "Hard"
            }
        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Difficulty>().HasData(difficuties);


        var regions = new List<Region>()
        {
            new Region
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("3a5d1dd2-abc5-412b-9e3d-c1b2648a228f"),
                Name = "Ha Noi",
                Code = "HN",
                RegionImageUrl = ""
            },
            new Region
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("22715dff-abad-4263-837a-9e97d80fa86d"),
                Name = "Sai Gon",
                Code = "SG",
                RegionImageUrl = ""
            },
             new Region
             {
                 Id = Guid.Parse("bc562c11-d7b2-478b-a75d-56a8da71b85a"),
                 Name = "Da Nang",
                 Code = "DN",
                 RegionImageUrl = ""
             },
             new Region
             {
                 Id = Guid.Parse("76675766-473f-4d1d-aba3-e4673f805d0c"),
                 Name = "Ninh Binh",
                 Code = "NB",
                 RegionImageUrl = ""
             }
        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>().HasData(regions);
   
    }
}

That is my dbcontext where I seeded some data
This is my Controller
private readonly IMapper mapper;
private readonly IWalkRepository walkRepository;

public WalksController(IMapper mapper, IWalkRepository walkRepository)
{
    this.mapper = mapper;
    this.walkRepository = walkRepository;
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateAndUpdateWalkDTO createAndUpdateWalkDTO)
{
    // map from createDTO to model
    var createWalkModel = mapper.Map<Walk>(createAndUpdateWalkDTO);

    await walkRepository.CreateAsync(createWalkModel);

    //map from model to dto to return
    return Ok(mapper.Map<WalkDTO>(createWalkModel));
}

Create and Update DTO
public class CreateAndUpdateWalkDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double LengthInKm { get; set; }
    public string? WalkImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Guid DiffcultyId { get; set; }
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }


}

Walk DTO
public class WalkDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double LengthInKm { get; set; }
    public string? WalkImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Guid DiffcultyId { get; set; }
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }
}

My object i send from client
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "This is description",
  "lengthInKm": 10,
  "walkImageUrl": null,
  "diffcultyId": "f5a9b531-a099-493a-a05a-81c95627adbc",
  "regionId": "3a5d1dd2-abc5-412b-9e3d-c1b2648a228f"
}


Please don't post pictures of code. You posted the first code snipper correctly so I'm not sure why you wouldn't post the second correctly too.

im so sorry for that, i edited my post sir

I could be wrong but I suspect that it's because you're using code to generate the IDs rather than constants. I saw something similar using DateTime.Now, although that value was actually different each time, sop maybe it's not the same thing. Not sure how you get around that for GUID values though.

Does it really make sense to be using GUIDs for those IDs anyway? Maybe that's something that you can't change now but you should generally only be using GUIDs if the IDs are being generated on multiple different systems. GUIDs have a very low likelihood of duplication even in that scenario, while integers would require different ranges to be assigned to maintain uniqueness. GUIDs are inefficient in use though, so if you're only generating the keys on a single system and especially if it's hard-coded data that will not be added to later, you really should be using integer IDs.

because that is not constants so i have to hard code the Id and parse them to Guid. When i called api i had copied two FK from db

do you think that i should use different type of Id like Int?

Let me try and im gonna feedback later! Thank you sir

Regardless of this issue, you should always use an integer data type for your PK if possible. As I said, GUIDs are far less efficient, so they should only be used if required. There may be other reasons but the most common reason for using GUIDs as a PK is their being generated on multiple client systems rather than all on the same server.

If you are going to stick with GUIDs, this a real stab in the dark but try using a Guid constructor instead of Guid.Parse.

The error clearly tells you that the FK being used, isn't a value in the primary key field of the foreign table.   Have you verified that your table is being populated as expected by your seeding method?

@jmcilhinney -- under the hood, there's no difference between the constructor and the static parse method.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915966/guid-parse-or-new-guid-whats-the-difference

I have checked all the data in two tables 2 seeded and it came to my expectation

@StephenWrighton, I thought that may be the case but was clutching at straws. As it turns out, I actually didn't read the question properly and was trying to solve the wrong problem. Your first comment made me realise my mistake.

@PhạmTrọngNghĩa, my apologies but I completely misunderstood the issue so, while you should still change the ID data type if possible, anything else I said is irrelevant. I thought the issue was inserting the seed data, but it appears it's actually with inserting data that is related to those seed records. You haven't actually showed us where you try to perform the insert that failed so we can't really see what's wrong with it. I suggest that you write some test code with hard-coded FK values copied from that seed data.

@jmcilhinney no problem i feel very grateful that you are helping me. This is my object i send from client to create:
{
  "name": "example name",
  "description": "this is the discription",
  "lengthInKm": 10,
  "walkImageUrl": null,
  "diffcultyId": "ce6a68d1-b490-4d38-a162-21ce3c371bfa",
  "regionId": "22715dff-abad-4263-837a-9e97d80fa86d"
}


and this is my controller
`
[HttpPost]
public async Task Create([FromBody] CreateAndUpdateWalkDTO createAndUpdateWalkDTO)
{
// map from createDTO to model
var createWalkModel = mapper.Map(createAndUpdateWalkDTO);
await walkRepository.CreateAsync(createWalkModel);

//map from model to dto to return
return Ok(mapper.Map<WalkDTO>(createWalkModel));

}
`
sorry i dont know how to create code field in comment :(

this is my source code https://github.com/phamnghiascode/Nghia

Don't post code in comments or links to code. Please edit your question and provide all relevant information there. Unlike a forum, where posts should generally not be edited unless they contain mistakes, SO questions should be edited if new information is required. The question should always be the source of truth. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

@jmcilhinney sorry sir, i edited my question and push some more code

After many days of trying, I realized my stupidity came from creating and sending the wrong object. This is wrong object
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "This is description",
  "lengthInKm": 10,
  "walkImageUrl": null,
  "diffcultyId": "f5a9b531-a099-493a-a05a-81c95627adbc",
  "regionId": "3a5d1dd2-abc5-412b-9e3d-c1b2648a228f"
}

and the problem is the "diffcultyId" spelling mistake. It has to be "diffcultyId"
